# Remov all words that are longer than two characers

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

I want to remove all words in nodepad++ that are longer than 2 chars. I know how to find two letter words:

`^[a-zA-Z]{2}$`

However, I want to remove all words that are larger. Any recommendations how to do that?

BR!

**UPDATE**

This is how my data look like:
[image]

**UPDATE**

Some sample data from the file:

```
 AF | AX                         AL                          
DZ                          
 AS                          
AD                          
ANGOLA                          AO
```

Comment: What do you mean by word? What is your text a letter, a dictionary, alpha-numeric list of words? would "BR!" be a "three letter word" or a two letter (characters) word? Would you also remove a following comma, if present?

Comment: Is the search&replace in regex mode? Is there a space in front of the pattern?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz  I just want to have all AF, AX, AL etc. in my textfile without all country names

Comment: @L3viathan I uploaded my input again. I also checked for " " in front and after the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, instead of specifying `2` as the size, you say "3 or more"; `3,`.

`[a-zA-Z]{3,}`

Comment: When I put this regex into notepad++ Replace All with " ", I get 0 results found...

Comment: This should work. Can you provide some sample data? It will only match words that are alone on one line, if you want to match them anywhere, remove the `^` and `$`.

Comment: Please have a look at my Update

Comment: Then remove the `^` and `$` from my regex, as edited. Also make sure to complete your set of word-characters, as words including `-` will not get caught by this. Consider replacing `[a-zA-Z]` with `\w`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\S+$
```

EDIT: This matches only full lines
from your sample it looks like you want

```
\s*[a-z]{2}\S+\s*
```

This will also trim the whitespace

Comment: This will also match e.g. a combination of a two letter word and a space afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
[^\s]{3,}
```

This will match any non-space character string that is at least 3 letters long with no maximum

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your words are not one per line, so remove the `^`:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3,}
```

The regex will match from start of word automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like NP++ has a very inmature RX implementation.

Try VI or replace in 2 steps:

Replace 
`[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]+`
 by empty, then replace `[\t ]+` by empty.